# I am getting exceptions in this program of reading strings and unable to figure it out

Tags: java

I am doing this program on Reading characters and I have types as it is that is there in the book.But still I am getting exceptions.

```
package Applets;

import java.io.*;

public class BRead extends InputStream{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        throws IOException   
        {
            char c;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("enter characters,'q' to quit");
            do{
                c=(char) br.read();
                System.out.println(c);
            }while(c!='q')
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell mw why the exceptions are coming??

Comment: What exception are you getting? Please share the stacktrace

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after the while

Answer (score 2):

Your class extends InputStream so it need to implement the abstract method read. Moreover you have some syntax errors as well, the correct version will be like this

```
import java.io.*;

public class BRead extends InputStream {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        char c;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter characters,'q' to quit");
        do {
            c = (char) br.read();
            System.out.println(c);
        } while (c != 'q');
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0; //change it as per your need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are doing many syntax errors in your code.
Please find the below code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BRead extends InputStream {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        char c;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter characters,'q' to quit");
        do {
            c = (char) br.read();
            System.out.println(c);
        } while (c != 'q');
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```